# Php7.3 Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel, count, php-7.3

I switch to PHP 7.3 and i get the same problem like other people on this error ( Parameter must be an array.. .)

I try to modify without success so i post this post.

My code is :

```
$i = $this->show($user->id);
$a = json_decode($i);

for ($b = 0; $b < sizeof($a->data); $b++)
```

The error it's from the "for".

I use Laravel.

Do you know how can i modify this line?

Thnks

Comment: Could you insert a var_dump($a); and tell us the result?

Comment: i try with "var_dump($a->data);" and i get "NULL"

Comment: What is `$i` meant to be?

Comment: When I upgraded to 7.2 I had to go through my codebase and change several instances like this to include null checks. In previous versions it was acceptable but now it isn't. `sizeof` or `count` expect an array or something that implements `Countable`- [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Rwd: $i  it's the id of the user ( from CRM Database)

Comment: Are there times when it can be `null`?

Comment: Sorry i was wrong. This is the code:

$i=$this->show($user->id);
//var_dump($i);

$a=json_decode($i);

So $i it's the user ID (working) and $a it's json_decode form him

The var dump of $i it's working but the $a (json_decode) return NULL

I hope I expressed myself well

Comment: So `$i` isn't `JSON`? Please can you show the output of `var_dump($i);`.

Comment: What is `show()` method?

Comment: I think i understand a little bit more. When i decompose the code.

With '$i=$this->show($user->id);' 
i get 'DATA:NULL'.

So when i do '$a=json_decode($i); ' i get  'Null' when i call '$a' 

I think it's the reason of my bug but i still don't know how to fix this with the new php version.

'for( $b=0; $b<sizeof($a->data); $b++ )'

I suppose the 'sizeof' don't understand the result 'NULL' and display
'sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable'


Solution ?

Comment: RWD: `var_dump($i);` give
string(118) "{"success":true,"data":null,"additional_data":{"pagination":{"start":0,"limit":200,"more_items_in_collection":false}}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, thanks for your help.

Second: I found the solution and you know what ? is not the code ... but the database.

After few hours to search i found some structure problem in my database. So i fix it i try again the script and ... Work.

I close this post.